# Transform a raw image to BMP color image

Tags: rgb, pixel

Now, I have finished reading the raw image from CMOS camera and calculate the R,G,B Red Green Blue by using bilinear interpolation already. The question is, i've just read a sample code have this part:

```
image_t = (unsigned char *)malloc((size_t)width * height * 3);

*(image_t + 3 * (width * y + x) + 2) = R;
*(image_t + 3 * (width * y + x) + 1) = G;
*(image_t + 3 * (width * y + x) + 0) = B;
```

I think image_t is a memory space for pixel to contain RGB value. But i'm not clear why do we need to add image_t with `3 * (width * y + x) + 2` for R?

As I know `(**width * y + x**)` is the location of pixel in the array. How about **3** and addition 2,1,0 for R,G,B, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

`image_t` is a pointer to an area of memory containing the image data. Its length is `width * height * 3`: the width of the image in pixels, times the height of the image in pixels, times the number of bytes per pixel.

Each pixel in this image is 3 bytes: one byte each for the R, G, and B values. So the location of the pixel in the array is actually `3 * (width * y + x)`. That's where the **3** comes from.

The 2, 1, and 0 are the byte offsets of the R, G, and B values within the pixel. R is at the pixel position + 2, G is at the pixel position + 1, and B is at the pixel position + 0.

Comment: Thanks,i haven't got enough reputation score. So i can't vote up for you.

Comment: Dear pmcoltrane, may you take a look at my program and explain why i couldn't read the BMP image? My code got no error but the BMP file is not ok.

Comment: @user3342390 the best thing to do would be to post another question, including the relevant portion of code, and what problem you're seeing with the bitmap.